# How to get if url rewrite in apache is possible/enabled?

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, apache2

How to test if a url rewrite is possible under apache2 ? I mean, not to determind if the urlrewrite module is loaded, but if its enabled/possible through config ?

Comment: put some garbage in `.htaccess` file. If the server responds with 500 status code, then you need to check if `mod_rewrite` is enabled.

Comment: @hjpotter92 .htaccess and mod_rewrite are totally different things. htaccess is just a per-dir context such as directory, but it's made to allow "non-admins" to add directives and affect a directory configuration.

Comment: @Bernd Kohlstedt The question is kind of confusing. What are you trying to accomplish exactly? URL rewriting is always possible as long as the necessary modules are loaded, and not only with mod_rewrite, but also with mod_alias Redirect/RedirectMatch. mod_rewrite just needs RewriteEngine on for it to work though, while Redirect/RedirectMatch just need to be defined.

Comment: @ezra-s I know. If by putting some garbage in htaccess, you're not getting any 500 errors, then your `AllowOverride` directive has been disabled. If it does result in 500, then checking for `mod-rewrite` is as easy as putting a `RewriteEngine on` in it and checking if it still results in 500 error or not.

Comment: @hjpotter92 whatever happens with htaccess, being allowed or not, does not have anything to do with rewriting, that's what I'm trying to tell. And the original question does not say anything about .htaccess being enabled or not. (the question is all but specific btw..)